# The status of the sum: $\sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{{k \choose m}}{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I would like to know the status of the sum: $$\sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{{k \choose m}}{k+1}.$$ Is it doable by hand in a closed form? If yes, what/where are the solutions? Please help.

Comment: If it is then Gosper's algorithm will find the solution.

Comment: ... which brings the question what the closed form is (at present). Gosper's algorithm would refuse to handle $m=0$ (say).